Is there a way to refresh Power BI snapshot inserted in a Power Point Presentation automatically?
I have a power point presentation that have some snapshots from Power Bi that I have to send weekly.
The thing is that I need to update all data snapshots (Basically, just changing some fields in comboboxes) and this take a lot of time.
Is there any possible way to update the snapshots automatically using vba or another microsoft office language?

In Powerpoint go to Settings and select the Developer Tab. Then Record a Macro doing what you do manually. Then check the Marco code generated and ask ChatGpt to automate it using variables and refreshing certain snapshots. If you are looking for another tool to do manual tasks automatically and there is no Programming Language to automate it then you can try SikuliX.

Seems to me a wrong use of Power BI. Instead of sending a PowerPoint with screenshots of the Power BI charts, publish the Power BI report or a dashboard to the intended audience and let them access the info directly. That's what Power BI was invented for.

If your snapshots are linked rather than embedded, you can update them using File>Info>Edit Links to Files. No VBA required. Please ignore Jeremy's reply: there hasn't been a macro recorder in PowerPoint for 20 years.

In the Microsoft 365 version of PowerPoint, you can insert a live, interactive Power BI report into a PowerPoint presentation. It will automatically update when the slide containing the report is displayed.
Do you have this button on the Insert tab of the PowerPoint Ribbon?

That will addd the Power BI container object to the current slide, which allows you to paste the Power BI URL:


The PPT connector now has an option for "Snapshot" vs "Live Data."  If you have Live data turned on, every time you open the page of the PPT it will update (if it's been more than the amount of time you have configured for the refreshes).
This is less than useful if you want a PPT saved with historical records.  If you use the snapshot (either private or public), then you can click the arrow at the top-right of the Power BI Object and click RELOAD. Or you can update by toggling to live and then back again.
If you have filters on your report that you are changing ... e.g. updating date span to last week's dates - then I would recommend you set up a date table with a column for week offset (and month offset, if you have monthly reports).  You would then filter your PPT to week offset = -1 (for Last week) and never have to change filters in PPT.  If you want, for instance, the last six weeks, you could have a column on your date table that says "Yes" if the date is in the last 6 weeks, then you would filter your report to that column = "Yes" - and again, never have to touch it.
Further - if you can make the Power BI report look exactly like the slides you want - you can have Power Automate create the slide deck for you and save it off to Sharepoint so there's a historical record of what the report looked like for that week (or email it to whomever wants it, etc).
The date table with Offset columns could look something like this (part of script from Radacad, though, note I adjusted it to a week being from Saturday to Friday... that was my need):
Date = 
//************** Script developed by RADACAD - edition: July 2021 
//************** set the variables below for your custom date table setting 
var _fromYear=YEAR(TODAY()) - 3 // set the start year of the date dimension. dates start from 1st of January of this year
var _toYear=YEAR(TODAY())   // set the end year of the date dimension. dates end at 31st of December of this year
var _startOfFiscalYear=1 // set the month number that is start of the financial year. example; if fiscal year start is July, value is 7
//************** 
var _today=TODAY()
return
ADDCOLUMNS(
    CALENDAR(
                DATE(_fromYear,1,1),
                DATE(_toYear,12,31)
),
"Year",YEAR([Date]),
"Start of Year",DATE( YEAR([Date]),1,1),
"End of Year",DATE( YEAR([Date]),12,31),
"Month",MONTH([Date]),
"Start of Month",DATE( YEAR([Date]), MONTH([Date]), 1),
"End of Month",EOMONTH([Date],0),
"Day Offset",DATEDIFF(_today,[Date],DAY),
"Week Offset", DATEDIFF(_today+1,[Date]+1, WEEK),
"Month Offset",DATEDIFF(_today,[Date],MONTH),
"Quarter Offset",DATEDIFF(_today,[Date],QUARTER),
"Is6weeksPlusMinus", IF( [Date] >=  (TODAY()+1-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-6)) - 42 && [Date] < (TODAY()+1-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-6)) + 42, "Yes","No")
)

